# not able to get the token from azure active directory by pass username and password for gmail user

Tags: c#, azure-ad-graph-api

i am trying the following method to get the access token from azure active directory

my code in c sharp is as below

```
   public async Task<string> validateADPCredential(string data)
    {
        data = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(data);
        ADPCredential adpCredential = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ADPCredential>(data);

        try
        {
            string clientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["azureclient_id"];
            string clientSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["azureclient_secret"];
            string tenant = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["tenantId"];
            string resource = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["resource"];

            var authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + tenant;


            var azureAdEndpoint = new Uri("https://login.microsoftonline.com/eshaweb.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/token");
            var urlEncodedContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
            {
               new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "password"),


               new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_id", clientId), //using the api client id
               new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username", adpCredential.Username),
               new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", adpCredential.Password),
               new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_secret", clientSecret),
               new KeyValuePair<string, string>("scope", "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"),

        });

            HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
            var result = await httpClient.PostAsync(azureAdEndpoint, urlEncodedContent);
            {
                var content = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                var authResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(content);
                return authResult.access_token;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
        return string.Empty;

    }
```

this code is working fine and i able to get the token for for internal user of active directory.but for gmail user(external user) i am getting the  following error.

```
{{
```

"error": "invalid_grant",
  "error_description": "AADSTS50034: The user account {EmailHidden} does not exist in the esheb.onmicrosoft.com directory. To sign into this application, the account must be added to the directory.\r\nTrace ID: 0222e890-a19e-4694-a004-327f2312aa00\r\nCorrelation ID: 8587e63d-9cd-4257-aa6c-1ef394d03f56\r\nTimestamp: 2020-06-09 16:57:03Z",
  "error_codes": [
    50034
  ],
  "timestamp": "2020-06-09 16:57:03Z",
  "trace_id": "0222e90-a19e-4694-a004-327f2312aa00",
  "correlation_id": "8587e63d-c6d-4257-aa6c-1ef394d03f56",
  "error_uri": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/error?code=50034"
}}

again if i tried to get the token in the following method

```
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow
```

i am able to get the token for internal and external user of the azure active directory.

can any one find out the solution for me .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not supported for gmail user(external user) to use ROPC, you can find the document as below.

> Personal accounts that are invited to an Azure AD tenant can't use
>   ROPC(Resource Owner Password Credentials).

[image]

Reference:

[Microsoft identity platform and OAuth 2.0 Resource Owner Password Credentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc)

Comment: but using the authentication  code method i can get the token for gmail also

Comment: @rakshithrai Yes, authentication code flow is another flow. This is not supported only for ropc flow.

Comment: can use the authentication flow in c sharp only.by passing username and password.anyway i need the token for a external user .any posibility?

Comment: @rakshithrai What do you want to do with the token? You can also use client credential flow which doesn't need user interaction. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service

Comment: @rakshithrai If you must get access on behalf of a user(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user), the only way for external user is using auth code flow.

Comment: thank you,@tony ju ,in the above method there is no option to enter username and password for the  user right.then how it validate the user

Comment: @rakshithrai See the comment above, there are two ways to get the access token, one for application, one for user. For the client credential flow(without user interaction), the application will be able to access all the users.

Comment: ya in both cases we need a login in admin account right?if i am using it in a browser in that browser the admin must be logd in.

Comment: @rakshithrai Not really, if you have granted your application admin consent, there is no need to login in admin account again. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-permissions-and-consent