# how to get the azure active directory token for the externl user using the windows application

Tags: c#, winforms, azure-active-directory

I Have Added the Gmail User to the Active Directory . For that user i tried to get token .As i asked in the quesion in stack overflow

[not able to get the token from azure active directory by pass username and password for gmail user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62288893/not-able-to-get-the-token-from-azure-active-directory-by-pass-username-and-passw)

but i failed to get the token using webapplication.

then i tried to get the token using the windows form application as in the microsoft documentation

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-desktop-msgraph-v2

again i falied for get token for gmail user. please help me to get the token for gmail(external user).can any one plese sujjest  me to get the token.

Comment: Do you want to use an application-only to obtain an access token? (This has no user interaction)

Comment: actually i need the access token inside the windows form appication.aculay for azure ad internal user user there are several methods[windows form interactive,passing username,password to web api etc] i am still able to recive the token.but i need token for external users[gmail]

Comment: i dont know y this quesion is downvoted

Comment: @tony-ju any solutions you have?

Comment: @carl-zhao i ok even user interaction method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In app.cs file of the sample application(git) chage the

```
private static string Instance = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/";
```

to

```
private static string Instance = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tennant}/oauth2/";
```

Your code will work for the external users also..